# Paypal Express Checkout not returning users back to website to confirm payment which breaks IPN

Tags: coldfusion, paypal, paypal-ipn

we are currently working on connecting Paypal to our website using the express checkout. At present we have a stable form that posts to paypal each time an order is required for payment.

We arent using the REST API but may do so in the future.

The issue we have is that some orders when processed dont appear to land back on our website following the IPN.

This then means our site admins dont see that an order has processed via paypal because the user hasnt opted to wait to come back to our website.

To add further frustration to the mix, the paypal website's documentation isnt the most user friendly and is hard to find anything meaningful on their site.

Would anyone know of any good way to check whether payments have landed inside paypal for a transaction easily ? This way we can catch onto whether a user has decided to close their window down after they have made payment via paypal which appears to be the common thing... instead of waiting for paypal to redirect back to our site

thanks in advance

BTW... we are using coldfusion for this, but if there is any coding examples in other languages its more than welcome as we could most likely translate it into our own code

Comment: IPN is a separate system that should not depend on the user returning. The IPN fires off to a webhook which you should process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the Express Checkout flow. Gonna give examples in Classic API (NVP is still the easiest way to do API calls, IMO)

1. **SetExpressCheckout** - You send order details to Paypal, along with a return URL
2. Your SEC call returns a token. You bounce the user to Paypal, using that token
3. User logs into Paypal and confirms they want to proceed
4. Paypal bounces the user back to the URL in your SEC call in step #1. Paypal adds the token from step #2 to the URL
5. You do a **GetExpressCheckoutDetails** call with the token and now you have all the user's details (shipping, etc).
6. You show the user a review page now (this is optional but a best practice) and they confirm the final order
7. You do a **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** call with the token and capture funds
8. PROFIT (optional but probably important)
9. You get an IPN notice